# How can I make a secondary Mongo database replica in my local computer from an Atlas cloud database?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a Mongo database on the Atlas Cloud service (free tier) that I need to make a secondary replica on my local computer. The idea is to have changes in my computer copy automatically synced into the primary database (on the Atlas Cloud service). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Short answer: **Not possible**. Long answer: Your MongoDB should be visible over the internet, since cluster members need to have connection between each node + it must have same time synchronization, otherwise the replication won't work as expected

Comment: @Valijon Is there a way to update it manually? Kindly consider putting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really do much of anything with a free-tier cluster except use it where it sits.

If by "secondary replica" you mean a standalone mongodb instance running in your local machine that has all the same data, the you should be able to use [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/index.html#mongodump) to export your data from Atlas and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/index.html#mongorestore) to import it to a local instance.